# CMake: undefined symbol when linking an executable with an OBJECT target which linked to a Shared Library

Tags: c++, cmake, undefined-reference, undefined-symbol

To be summarized, I have an Object target (`a_object`) which is `PUBLIC` linked to a Shared Library (`base`). The Object target is compiled fine, however when I link that Object target to an executable (`main`), I got undefined symbol error from a function in `base` library when building that executable.

For more details:

##### Project tree

```
src
+---base
|       CMakeLists.txt
|       parser_helper.cpp
|       parser_helper.hpp
|
\---module
        a.cpp
        a.hpp
        CMakeLists.txt
        main.cpp
```

##### Sources files:

###### `base/parser_helper.hpp`

```cpp
#include <istream>
#include <string>

namespace base {
  class line : public std::string {
   public:
    friend auto operator>>(std::istream& is, line& line) -> std::istream&;
  };
}   // namespace base
```

###### `base/parser_helper.hpp`

```cpp
#include "base/parser_helper.hpp"

namespace {
  using base::line;
}   // namespace

auto base::operator>>(std::istream& is, line& line) -> std::istream& {
  return std::getline(is, line);
}
```

###### `base/CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_library(base SHARED parser_helper.cpp parser_helper.hpp)
target_compile_options(base PRIVATE ...)
target_compile_features(base PRIVATE ...)
target_include_directories(base PRIVATE ...)
```

###### `module/a.hpp`

```cpp
#include <istream>

namespace longlp {
  void f(std::istream& input_stream);
  ...
}   // namespace longlp
```

###### `module/a.cpp`

```cpp
#include "module/a.hpp"

#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#include "base/parser_helper.hpp"

namespace {
  using base::line;
}   // namespace

namespace longlp {
  void f(std::istream& input_stream) {
    std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<line>(input_stream),
                  std::istream_iterator<line>(),
                  [](const line& line) {
                    // ...
                  });
  }
}   // namespace longlp
```

###### `module/main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include "module/a.hpp"

int main() {
  std::stringstream input("123\n123");
  longlp::f(input);

  return 0;
}
```

###### `module/CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_library(a_object OBJECT)
target_sources(a_object PRIVATE a.cpp a.hpp)
target_compile_options(a_object PRIVATE ...)
target_compile_features(a_object PRIVATE ...)
target_include_directories(a_object PRIVATE ...)
target_link_libraries(a_object PUBLIC base)

add_executable(main)
target_sources(main PRIVATE main.cpp)
target_compile_options(main PRIVATE ...)
target_compile_features(main PRIVATE ...)
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ...)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE a_object)
```

##### Error log when building `main`

```
[build] lld-link: error: undefined symbol: class std::basic_istream<char, struct std::char_traits<char>> & __cdecl base::operator>>(class std::basic_istream<char, struct std::char_traits<char>> &, class base::line &)
[build] >>> referenced by C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\iterator:290
[build] >>>               src/module/CMakeFiles/a_object.dir/a.cpp.obj:(private: void __cdecl std::istream_iterator<class base::line, char, struct std::char_traits<char>, __int64>::_Getval(void))
```

I got no error when building `a_object` individually. From [Cmake documentation on linking Object target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#linking-object-libraries), I think it is enough to just linking the `a_object` to `main`, am I missing something?

Comment: Which compiler/build system are you using? If it's Visual Studio with the default compiler, you're definetly missing `__dllspec(dllimport)`/`_dllspec(dllexport)` in `parse_helper.hpp` for the class and the operator... However I doubt you're using the visual studio default compile tools since this would have resulted in base.lib not being created, since there are no exported symbols... Btw: is there a specific reason not to use `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, line& line);` and use a tailing return type here? Imho this just makes for longer and harder to read code without a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Writing the files straight into the `add_library` instead of the `target_sources` might work.
Also, write a global `CMakeLists.txt` file and link everything there.